# configuration for 1 worker node cluster in spark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I am running spark standalone on 1 node cluster(1 driver, 1 worker node). The driver node have configuration: 8 cores, 16 gb ram, worker node: 24gb ram,8 core.

Is it possible to leverage driver node also with  worker in better way like by having executor running on it effectively? Can somebody please help me to configure the params for this configuration?

Thanks and Regards,
Sudip

Comment: If your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66052495/how-to-configure-worker-node-with-driver-for-spark-standalone-cluster) was closed, posting it again will not help. Learn about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: instead of closing the question, please tell me what's wrong in the question, I tried my best to pinpoint as much as possible where I am stuck, the worst thing that can happen is to close the question pointing to generic posts...

Comment: You did not pinpoint the problem. Your problem is extremely broad and will be closed as needs more focus.